# Result z*conj(z) with z complex - TI-Nspire CAS

Tags: ti-nspire

When I write z*conj(z) on TI-Nspire CAS, the result is z^2 (true only if z is real) instead of |z|^2. Is there a way to get the right result |z|^2?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All undefined variables are treated as real variables. Therefore `z` will be seen as a real (even in rectangular mode).

The alternative is to use:

```
z := a + b*@i
z*conj(z)
```

which gives the result `a^2+b^2`.

Answer (score 0):

Or other alternative:

```
a:=√(z^2)
z*conj(a)
```